# Where can I find a free, usable shapefile for the prehistoric super continent, Pangaea?

Tags: python, arcgis

I want to write a python script where I split a Pangaea shapefile to eventually display the continents as they are today.  Where can I find Pangaea data, specfically shapefiles?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a [shapefile for Pangea with plate boundaries here](http://www.earthbyte.org/Resources/gplates-alternative_rotation_files.html), it appears.